# React Component not Rerendering on Property Change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two files: TrainingGround.js and Rectangle.js.

**TrainingGround.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Rectangle, RectangleComponent } from './Rectangle';

export class TrainingGround extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      rect: new Rectangle(10, 20, 5, 10, 0),
    };
    this.rotate = this.rotate.bind(this);
  }

  rotate() {
    this.state.rect.rotateDeg(45);
    console.log(this.state.rect.vertices);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.rotate}>
        <RectangleComponent
          w={this.state.rect.boundingWidth}
          h={this.state.rect.boundingHeight}
          position={this.state.rect.center}
          vertices={this.state.rect.vertices}
        ></RectangleComponent>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I call `this.state.rect.rotateDeg(45)`, the values of `this.state.rect.vertices` is assigned a new array (i.e. the array is not simply modified). However, this doesn't seem to trigger a rerender of `RectangleComponent`. I can confirm this change with the `console.log()` statement below it.

**Rectangle.js**

```js
...
export class RectangleComponent extends React.Component {
  get polygonStr() {
    // Create str of vertices, e.g. '1px 2px, 3px 4px, ...'
    const verticesStr = this.props.vertices.map((e) => e.map((f) => f + 'px').join(' ')).join(', ');
    return `polygon(${verticesStr})`;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          position: 'relative',
          clipPath: this.polygonStr, // vertices should change, updating this value
          backgroundColor: '#000',
          width: this.props.w + 'px',
          height: this.props.h + 'px',
          top: this.props.position[1] + 'px',
          left: this.props.position[0] + 'px',
        }}
      ></div>
    );
  }
}
```

Why isn't the component updated in this case?

---

It seems like this is a common issue other new React developers face. I've checked out other questions similar to this, but I'm still scratching my head why this wouldn't update.

My understanding is that a component will rerender when either:

- Its state changes
- Its properties change

With the exception of mutable objects for either (which shouldn't be the case in my above example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your rotate method to set a new state instead of changing in the state

```
rotate() {
    // this.state.rect.rotateDeg(45); <-- Do not do this
    const newRect = new Rectangle(10, 20, 5, 10, 45) //<-- Create new state
    this.setState({rect: newRect}) //<-- Set new state 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to doing it like below

```
rotate() {
  const rect ={...this.state.rect}
  rect.rotateDeg(45);
  this.setState({rect});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not allowed to update any `this.state` by link as you did.

React component re-render itself in two cases:

a. any state property is changed (only using this.setState method)

b. any props passed down to this component is changed.

in your example you better do next:

1. put your instance of Rectangle in this.rectangle.
2. editable value should be inside `this.state` and being changed properly(only through `this.setState`)
3. update your rectangle instance whenever your component is updating.

```
{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      angle: 0,
    }
    this.rectangle = new Rectangle(10, 20, 5, 10, 0);
  }

  rotate = (angle) => {
    this.setState({ angle });
  }
  componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (this.state.angle !== nextState.angle) {
      this.rectangle.rotateDeg(nextState.angle);
    }
  }
}
```

it is easier to do using FC and hooks, tho.